# If I've been offered a job in Seattle, USA what is the best way to approach bringing my girlfriend with me?

Tags: united-kingdom, usa, visa

I'm a UK national and I've been offered a postdoc position in Seattle. I know I will have no problem getting a visa, but I also want my girlfriend (also a UK national and a marine biologist) to come with me. 
How would it be best to approach also getting her a visa? Could she latch onto mine or could she get a different visa?

Comment: The US doesn't offer immigration benefits to unmarried partners.  Would you consider marrying?  If not, she'd need to find a visa in her own right.

Comment: If you do get married and decide to petition for a F2 (dependent of F1-Student) visa for her, please keep in mind that she won't be able to work or study under the visa. I would recommend you both getting F1 visas even if you decide to get married.

Comment: @Ian Dantas As the OP is considering a postdoc position, if they marry wouldn't a J or H visa be more suitable?

Comment: @David I'm not aware of post-docs on H visas. Hs are usually work related visas. Since the primary reason for travel in this case is the pursuit for a degree, the OP will be primarily a student, therefore a F1 holder. As for a J visa, it could be the case if the OP is doing a exchange or is sponsored by an institution. Neither case is clear from what the OP posted. So, most likely he will be an F1. Moreover, being a J or H won't change the outcome. Neither would give the OP's girlfriend right to work as a dependent.

Comment: @IanDantas I agree that a girlfriend ≠ someone who'd be entitled to obtain a visa to work as a dependent. However, a "postdoc" in common parlance is a person who's already earned a PhD and who's employed on a contract or yearly basis as a university staff member, for pay. Postdocs are not working towards their own degrees, and are not students. I think, therefore, that the OP is not entitled to an F visa.

Comment: @David. Gotcha, I missed that part. In this case, yes, an F1 is not even a possibility. However, like I said as a J2 the spouse is bound to the same restriction (actually can be even more restrictions) as F2s and as a H4 she may not work either (there is one exception not applicable to the OP).